# File Path of Old Version of DLL Error Message

Tags: development, sharepoint-server, event-receivers

I am working on an Event Receiver and recently after doing a deployment to the farm. My Event Receiver just starts outputting a message to my log list that is the file path of the old version of my DLL.

My current version is 53 but in a path is pointing to 52. I'm not sure what this is. Has anyone else experienced this?

**Error**

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\MyEventReceiver\v4.0_1.0.0.52__5c2d2dc4858aa135\MyEventReceiver.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue on our farm around the year ago.We bring MSFT folks jump in and finally a very easy solution.

1. Restart the SharePoint Timer Service and Admin Service on all the server in the farm. So that old dll should recycle.